# Multiple chemical formulae next to one another

Tags: floats, subcaption, chemfig

I'm trying to get 3 subfigures containing a chemical formula each next to one another. Below is the document and the output. I know, that usually the subcaption package should put the subfigures next to each other. And with other images this works for me. Just not with chemfig figures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \setchemfig{atom sep=2em}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        % Acetone Structure Formel
        \chemfig{-[1](=[2]O)-[7]}
        \caption{Acetone}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        % THF Structure Formel 
        \chemfig{[:18]*5(---O--)}
        \caption{Tetrahydrofuran}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        % m-Xylene Structure Formel 
        \chemfig{CH3-[:-90]*6(=-(-CH3)=-=-)}
        \caption{m-Xylene}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    
    \label{fig:struct:acetone/thf}
    \caption{Strukturformeln der eingesetzten Chemikalien.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Produced Output with images next to one another]

Comment: Remove blank lines

Comment: using the egreg hint, you can reduce the distance between molecules using \begin{subfigure}{0.15\textwidth}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've well understood your problem, deleting the blanklines in the code is enough:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}
    \usepackage{chemfig}
    \usepackage{subcaption}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \setchemfig{atom sep=2em}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
            % Acetone Structure Formel
            \chemfig{-[1](=[2]O)-[7]}
            \caption{Acetone}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
            % THF Structure Formel
            \chemfig{[:18]*5(---O--)}
            \caption{Tetrahydrofuran}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
            \centering
            % m-Xylene Structure Formel
            \chemfig{CH3-[:-90]*6(=-(-CH3)=-=-)}
            \caption{m-Xylene}
        \end{subfigure}
        \label{fig:struct:acetone/thf}
        \caption{Strukturformeln der eingesetzten Chemikalien.}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is exactly what user comment "egreg" says.

Comment: Yes, I discovered that after I had posted. Great minds think together… ;-)

Comment: Wow thanks so much. I never would have guessed that blank lines would have an impact on this? Could you elaborate how this happens or is it simply that subcaption puts figures beneath one another if you put blank lines?

Comment: Well, a blank line is the standard way to introduce a new paragraph. B.t.w., for such constructions, you might also be interested by the `floatrow` package and its eponymous environment.